# how to pass expression value in to function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass an expression value in to function in angular js but it is not working. here is my code.

**Html**

```
   <div  ng-show="menuCtrl.isContactTab('AddressBook')" >
        <div ng-controller="Contacts as contacts" >
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" ng-repeat="names in contacts.addressbookNames">
                <li>
                    <a href ng-click="menuCtrl.setContactOptions('addressOption',names.id)">  {{names.firstName}} ,{{names.lastName}},{{names.id}}
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

here I want to pass {{names.id}} value in to setContactOptions function.

The controller code:

```
app.controller('MenuController', function(){
  this.contactTab=1;
  this.setContactOptions = function(optionType,id){ 
    this.contactOption = optionType; 
    this.contactId= id;
  }
});

app.controller('CaseloadController',function(){ 
  this.caseList = caseNames;
  this.selectedCase = null;
  this.idValue = this.contactId; 
});
```

but it is not assigning that contactId into idValue of another controller. how to get contactId value into this controller?

Comment: It should work, what is the problem..?

Comment: please show your js code

Comment: yes it is working but the problem is in controller class. here is my controller class.

Comment: You can't just assign a variable in one controller and access it in the other. That is unless the first controller inherits the second. What exactly are you trying to do?